# Prevent helm from prompting to create a new buffer

Tags: helm

If you visit a directory with `helm-find-files` and type the name of a file that doesn't exist, before opening it in a new buffer helm will prompt:

```
File does not exist, create buffer?
```

I would like helm to just create the buffer, without the prompt. I can't find an option for it to do this: essentially I want a variable just like `ido-create-new-buffer`.

Comment: I notice that `ffap-newfile-prompt` is `nil`, as I think it should be. `ffap.el` shows `((or (not ffap-newfile-prompt) (file-exists-p filename) (y-or-n-p "File does not exist, create buffer? ")) (funcall ffap-file-finder (expand-file-name filename)))`, so I'd have thought this would have worked, since I think helm is using this under the covers? (ffap.el line 1427, for me, Emacs 24.5.1.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set `helm-ff-newfile-prompt-p` to `nil` and Helm won't ask you anymore:

```
(setq helm-ff-newfile-prompt-p nil)
```